# How do I post information from a <form> and get information into the form from that also needs to be posted into the same database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm making a form that puts student information into a student table. Part of this information requires the foreign key as the parent_guardian_id from the parents table . I'd like to offer the parents' names as a choice from a select or dropdown to input the foreign key. It seems like I need to GET and POST at the same time? I would need to do this with at least 2 other pages. Thanks for any insight.

```
//Check for student first name:
if (empty($_POST['student_first_name'])) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter the student\'s first name.";
} else {
    $student_first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_POST['student_first_name'])); 
    }
if (empty($errors)){//If requirements met:        

    $query="INSERT INTO student (student_first_name, student_last_name,
            student_street, student_city, student_zip, student_phone,
            student_email,  parent_guardian_id)
        Values ('$student_first_name', '$student_last_name',
            '$student_street', '$student_city', '$student_zip', '$student_phone',
            '$student_email', '$parent_guardian_id')";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    if ($result){
        echo "<center><p><b>A new STUDENT has been added.</b></p><br/>"; 
        echo "<center><a href=studentadd.php>Show All STUDENTS</a> </center>"; 
        exit();
    } else {
      $errors[] = "<p>The record could not be added due to a system error. </p>";
      $errors[] = mysqli_error($dbc) . "</p>"; 
    }
}
}

mysqli_close($dbc);}

?>
<form action="studentadd.php" method="post">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="student_first_name" size="50"     value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_first_name']; ?>"/><p><br />
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="student_last_name" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_last_name']; ?>" /><p><br />
<p>Street Address: <input type="text" name="student_street" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_street']; ?>" /><p><br />
<p>City: <input type="text" name="student_city" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_city']; ?>"/><p><br />
<p>State: <input type="text" name="student_state" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_state']; ?>"/><p><br />
<p>Zip: <input type="text" name="student_zip" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_zip']; ?>"/><p><br />
<p>Phone: <input type="text" name="student_phone" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_phone']; ?>"/><p><br />
<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="student_email" size="50" value=
   "<?php echo $_POST['student_email']; ?>"/><p><br /></form>
<p>Parent/Guardian: <select name="parent_guardian" 
        id="parent_guardian" size="20" 
    value="<?php echo $row['mother_guardian_first_name'] . " 
        , " . $row['mother_guardian_last_name'] . "
        , " . $row['father_guardinan_first_name'] . "
        , " . $row['father_guardian_last_name'];
        $_POST['parent_guardian_id']; ?>"/>Name Goes Here</select><p><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" /></p>
</form>

<?php
//include the footer
include ("footer.php");

?>
```

Comment: HTML `<select>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. You need `<option>` tags, and you need to loop through your *select* query results. By the way, I don't see where you *select* the parents from the database. Oh, and the parent select is it outside the form. Hmmm.

Comment: On a side note: Use Prepared Statements. You're wide open to injection like this.

Comment: I have a lot of escape strings before this block of code. I placed one above. The value is the $row segments, which is apparently incorrect. So the select for the parents goes inside the form? This was what I was confused about. Thanks for the hints. If anyone could drop a link to some instructions on how to make this happen I would be very appreciative. Cheers.

Comment: Please read this post about how to prevent SQL injection.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php